# Remove empty dimension from multi-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this type of array `float[1][1][54][54]`. If it possible to cast this array to float[54][54]? Maybe it`s possible to remove two first empty dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cast it, but you can just assign the inner array to a new variable:

```
float[][][][] arr1 = new float[1][1][54][54];
float[][] arr2 = arr1[0][0];
```

Note that although they're separate variables, they actually share a reference to the same inner array, so they can't be modified separately.